# TextWatcher inside AlertDialog not working

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to implement a mask in the EditText, the EditText appears when the user clicks in a TextView field and a alertdialog pops up, that EditText is inside an AlertDialog, but somehow the 
listener is not working. What am I missing here?

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        numero = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_numero);

        numero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog("Text");
            }
        });
    }


    public void dialog(String titulo) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.observacao, null);

        EditText observacao = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numero);
        Mask.insert("###.###.###-##", observacao);

        TextView obslabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.obslabel);

        obslabel.setText(titulo);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



            }
        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.setView(view);

        dialog.show();
    }

    public static class Mask {
        public static String unmask(String s) {
            return s.replaceAll("[.]", "").replaceAll("[-]", "")
                    .replaceAll("[/]", "").replaceAll("[(]", "")
                    .replaceAll("[)]", "");
        }

        public static TextWatcher insert(final String mask, final EditText ediTxt) {
            return new TextWatcher() {
                boolean isUpdating;
                String old = "";

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                          int count) {
                    String str = Mask.unmask(s.toString());
                    String mascara = "";
                    if (isUpdating) {
                        old = str;
                        isUpdating = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    int i = 0;
                    for (char m : mask.toCharArray()) {
                        if (m != '#' && str.length() > old.length()) {
                            mascara += m;
                            continue;
                        }
                        try {
                            mascara += str.charAt(i);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            break;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    isUpdating = true;
                    ediTxt.setText(mascara);
                    ediTxt.setSelection(mascara.length());
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                              int after) {
                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `TextWatcher` you obtain by calling

> `Mask.insert("###.###.###-##", observacao);`

with the `EditText`, so change that line to

```
observacao.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("###.###.###-##", observacao));
```